# x64-based PC and Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a Windows XP OS. I have x64-based PC. Is it possible to install **WindowsXP** which is **32bit** OS onto a **x64-based PC**?

Comment: the answer is just a google search away!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. x86_64/AMD64/EMT64T supports the older 32 bit x86 instructions - it will merely run in [legacy mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Legacy_mode). Just remember the constraints of the system, such as the amount of ram the system supports.

You may have other issues though, for example with Windows XP not really supporting [AHCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface) very well, and needing to hunt down drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install a 32 bit (x86) on a 64 bit (x64) machine. Both "physical" (as in your main operating system) and virtual (as in a virtual machine). But you can **not** run a 64 bit OS on a 32 bit CPU (neither "physical" and virtual)

Comment: is this CPU a 64bit CPU: Intel® Pentium® processor T4500 ? it only support 64bit OS?

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA According to [http://ark.intel.com/products/42925/Intel-Pentium-Processor-T4500-(1M-Cache-2_30-GHz-800-MHz-FSB)](Intel) it is a 64 bit CPU, yes. It supports both 32 bit and 64 bit OS. However, if running 32 bit you can only use 3.25 GB of your memory. I'd recommend running 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Windows XP 32-bit on my 64-bit PC for more than 7 years... It's completely OK. If I were you I would not even think about putting 64-bit Windows XP on your machine. You will not see much faster performance comparing to 32-bit Win... However, you can try Ubuntu 64-bit if you want to or even Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit 90-day Trial Version... Here is a link to download it:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx

Beware, that there are some applications that will not run at all or not run properly on 64-bit Windows or 64-bit Ubuntu... (with 32-bit Windows or 32-bit Ubuntu you will have less problems with compatibility etc...)

Beware as well that the Microsoft support for Windows XP ends April 8, 2014 , so you have two years left before upgrading to Windows Vista, 7 or Windows 8...